# World Wide Web Publishing Service and HTTP.SYS

Tags: asp.net, iis, http.sys

I was reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#:%7E:text=HTTP%20Request%20Processing%20in%20IIS) article from Microsoft and in step 5 it says: `The WWW Service uses the configuration information to configure HTTP.sys.`

What exactly is the WWW service configure in HTTP.sys?
What is the purpose of the WWW service?
How is it different from the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In short, WWW service gets the configuration elements from `applicationHost.config` and applies the portion related to Windows HTTP API to the driver HTTP.sys.

The purpose of WWW service is roughly documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#how-the-www-service-works-in-iis

Don't try to acquire a deep understanding of such components at the beginning. They are not open sourced so he documentation is rather vague.

The same applies to WAS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#windows-process-activation-service-was

If you are taking a course, just memorize the facts at this stage. Once you get more familiar with IIS daily operations, you will get more insights.

Comment: what configurations are applied to http.sys from applicationhost.config?
it's not for a course it's for my own understanding, so I do want the deep details.

Comment: @GalSuchetzky Mostly related to site bindings. ASP.NET Core also can hook to HTTP.sys directly, so configuration from that side can be your reference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-6.0